# Pythonic way to go to next line when iterating over a multi-line string?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a multi-line variable called `text` that I'm iterating over, line by line.
First I need to look for a matching regex, then do some operations on the very following line.
So I was wondering if there was a neat/pythonic way to do this - the only thing I could think of was adding a boolean variable to keep track of whether or not the previous line contained the regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One pythonic way to iterate over adjacent pairs of elements uses [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with a 1-offset slice:

```
lines = text.split("\n")

for line1, line2 in zip(lines, lines[1:]):
    if whatever(line1):
        do_horrible_things(line2)
```

Here, `line2` would be an immutable string, so if you needed any changes to be reflected in `lines`, you would have to use indeces (as produced here by [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)):

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if whatever(line):
        lines[i+1] = do_horrible_things(lines[i+1]) 
        # and safeguard against line being the last one
```